# Foreman doesn't start with "Invalid gemspec" error

Tags: 11.10, ruby

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409805/foreman-command-not-found-in-ubuntu-11-04) post I am also trying to complete [this](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js) heroku tutorial

I have installed and used everything (node.js, npm, express) successfully until I got to Foreman. I installed Foreman by first installing Ruby:

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

then installing Foreman. I am a newbie to Unix so I "sudo" perhaps unnecessarily here, but I got confirmation in the terminal that it had installed but also some errors:

```
alex@ubuntu:~/NodeHelloWorld$ sudo gem install foreman
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/foreman-0.26.1.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/term-ansicolor-1.0.7.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/foreman-0.26.1.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/term-ansicolor-1.0.7.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Successfully installed term-ansicolor-1.0.7
Successfully installed foreman-0.26.1
```

Then when I try to start foreman I get similar:

```
alex@ubuntu:~/NodeHelloWorld$ foreman start
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/foreman-0.26.1.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-10 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/term-ansicolor-1.0.7.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem foreman (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/foreman:18
```

Can anyone help me? I am a newbie to Unix after finally dumping windows as I found I could not get [foreman-windows](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman-windows) to work for me either

I have found this post from someone with apparently the same issue. Does this mean my version of ruby could be wrong? I am running 1.9.1, though again new to ruby as well;

```
alex@ubuntu:~/NodeHelloWorld$ ruby1.9.1 -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this resolved by: **sudo gem update rails** OR **sudo gem update --system**, so that you re using the latest version(s)?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution - edit gemspec files by opening an admin "session":

<kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> then type `gksudo nautilus` and browse to, edit and save .gemspec files.

Both problem files require the dates edited from `2011-11-10 00:00:00.000000000Z` to `2011-11-10`

Comment: I did it with sudo mc and navigate to the files that needs to be edited, changed the time value and that was it. Thanks a lot for the solution.